# How can I burn a bootable dmg image?

Tags: burning

I have a bootable dmg image and I need to burn it to a double layer DVD (the only one I have right now).

I don't have Mac just my Ubuntu PC and I heard it's possible but searching google didn't answer my question. So would you please tell me how can I do that without damaging the file or the only DVD I have right now?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this seems to be converting the dmg to an iso file.

[Managing Disk Images](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManageDiscImages#DMG%20Images) on the Ubuntu wiki explains this very well for different formats including dmg.

Comment: Will this keep the image bootable ?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not 100% sure. I imagine that all settings for the CD are saved as binary in the DMG, therefore the ISO should represent *exactly* the same burned CD.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is 4 years later, but if I was pointed here others will be too.

1. Download *.dmg.
2. `sudo apt-get install dmg2img`
3. `dmg2img *.dmg *.img`
4. `brasero` (make data file... burn as *.iso)
5. `gparted` (select USB - unmount - make FAT32)
6. Mount the USB device.
7. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`
8. `sudo apt-get update`
9. `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`
10. `sudo unetbootin` (select disk image,point to *iso, your usb device should be in the top level of the drop down list, and burn it)
11. It will 'hang' in the middle and then it will install complete, so don't rush to judge and cancel while its in the middle of processing ;)

Comment: +1 for explaining how to convert `*.dmg` into `*.img` (and then `*.iso`). -1 for telling how to make a boot pendrive from a `*.dmg` instead of telling how to burn it to a disc.

Comment: Wont dmg2img *.dmg *.iso work? img is just an iso, so changing extension will work?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [all2iso](http://www.bebits.com/app/4065). You open a terminal and write

```
dmg2iso filename.dmg filename.iso
```

And that's all. It will be bootable, I have not tried with a .dmg file, but I've tried with other filetypes and all2iso.

Comment: The all2iso download link doesn't work, it says it's forbidden for my IP. Why? I have nver downloaded form here! Requires BeOS and their account info. Trying to fix MAC boot issue here but Can't use this one.